# How to parse String data using SimpleDataFormat?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm");
    try {
            Date date=format.parse("2012.9.11 02:00");
                            Log.i("date", date.toGMTString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("exception", e.getMessage());
        }
```

But I've got the message: "10 Sep 2012 22:00:00 GMT", i.e. incorrect date. How can I fix it?

Comment: parse interprets the string as a date in your local time zone, toGMTString() prints the date in GMT/UTC, that's why you see the different date in the output.

Comment: Look this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788889/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-a-date) it is very detailed.

Comment: @Денис Нагибин: Its a good practice to accept the helpful answer..

Answer (score 1):

That **IS** the correct date. It is calculated based on your GMT offset.

To print it like this `11-Sep-2012 02:00:00` use `date.toLocaleString()` (deprecated method)

Or you can print the date using the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class using:

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm");
Date date=format.parse("2012.09.11 02:00");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println(format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

This prints : `2012.09.11 02:00`

You can see http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html for more info

Comment: Just FYI `date.toLocaleString() ` is a deprecated method.

Comment: @Hardik Mishra I know, that's why i added the Calendar implementation

Comment: The example added after my comment.. :)

Comment: actually i was working on it, while you where posting your comment :P

Answer (score 0):

You're printing `date.toGMTString()` and so you get "10 Sep 2012 22:00:00 GMT" which isn't an incorrect string but the date in Greenwich Mean Time. Note that [toGMTString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toGMTString%28%29) is deprecated.

If you want to print your date in your format, you may do

```
 Log.i("date", format.format(date));
```

If you don't want to get supplementary "0", use

```
format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.M.d HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

As Per [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toGMTString%28%29),  `date.toGMTString()` is a deprecated method.

Its not good practice to use deprecated methods.

Use `date.toString()` instead of `date.toGMTString()`.

Or

`format.format(date);`

Answer (score 0):

The method `toGMTString()` is deprecated. 
However, as for an explanation, you might be in different time zone, thus have a different locale. 
Try replacing with `date.toLocaleString()` should output correctly, although also a deprecated method.

Comment: Isn't  date.toLocaleString() deprecated also ?

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect because you're using `date.toGMTString()`

Just try to output the variable `date` and you'll able to see the correct time!